# Is it possible for Powerline networking to cause erratic router behavior?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, home-networking, powerline-networking

I would like to know whether is it possible for Powerline networking causes erratic router behavior. Could there be any noise emitted from the electrical wiring of the house, and picked up by the router's wireless antenna? Or could it be possible that the noise affects the router (or other device) behavior via electrical supply?

The erratic behaviors I have encountered before are:
 - WiFi connection is detected on and off, router's web interface is sometimes accessible if connected.
 - LAN connection is stated as Unidentified Network on Windows, router's web interface is inaccessible via LAN.
 - Only partial of the computers connected on the network has working Internet connection. A different set of computers would work when the main LAN cable is connected to a different port on the router.

The same behaviors occurred throughout 4 routers, including a brand new one. However, the issues come and go as well at different time.

If Powerline networking is the cause, how can we detect it effectively?

Your constructive advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks~

Comment: I have heard about poerline interfering with radio bands, but now WiFi. And all the symptoms you have described look more like a dodgy router to me.

Comment: It's kinda unlikely that to be dodgy router, as I have tested on 4 routers, and actually not 1, but 2 routers are brand new, and different models. They are also widely acclaimed models, namely ASUS RT-N56U, and TP-LINK TL-WR841ND.

The prob seem to be standard across the router at a specific time. But the prob comes and goes.

Would appreciate if u can help to pinpoint what router prob is it though.

Comment: I am definitely in no position to judge the routers )) It was my initial guess.  Why are you susptecting the PowerLine coms? It might be any other RF interference. Are you aware of someone using PL in the same house?

Comment: Since you tried different routers, I assume you tried different clients? I am asking this just to make sure we can rule out the possibility of malfunctioning NIC.

Comment: Yes, I do found a Powerline adapter in use.

I am thinking of other RF interference as well, but can't really came up with any common device that could cause such prob.

Was also thinking that it could be neighbor's wireless signal interference, but again I think it doesn't look quite possible to cause any LAN connection issue - the router's web interface isn't accessible even via direct LAN connection to the router.

Comment: Well, if you have access/control to PowerLine adapters, then I would totally recommend you to start experimenting. Try to disconnect (if possible) all PowerLine adapters for a day or two and see if this has effect. Also try to generate as much traffic as you can over the PowerLine and see if the problem gets worse. I know its a little help, but when it comes to RF interference the best thing you can do is test different scenarios.

Comment: Btw, I had incomplete comment earlier. Plz kindly check the edit for any additional info useful. :)

Comment: In response to your last comment, would like to know is there any definitive troubleshooting method towards RF interference that u known of? On the other hand, do u think is it possible for Powerline networking to be directly causing erratic behavior of any functionality in the router?

Comment: Electric motors (e.g., the ones in your fridge and other major appliances) are notorious for causing noise on power lines; and I've heard that compact fluorescent lights (CFLs) are also bad for that. Depending on who you talk to, smart power meters could also be a major source of RF interference, but I think the jury's still out on that one.

Comment: @RobH The network was fine before this. Do you think it's possible that any device became bad? So, are u implying that RF interference could directly cause erratic behavior of the router?

Comment: I only mentioned it, because you mentioned RF interference in one of your comments. I think a well designed and well built router should be able to work properly regardless of RF interference.

Comment: As for whether or not a device has become bad, your only way to find that out is to try turning devices off and see if the problem goes away, then if it does turn those devices back on one by one to try to pinpoint which device is causing the problem. A quick way to pinpoint problem devices would be to use a binary search method of turning half of the devices off, and if the problem disappears, turn half of those back on to see if the problem returns; otherwise, turn the other half of the devices off. Keep narrowing it down by half until you find the problem device.

Comment: @RobH Thx for ur input. :)

Comment: Anymore advice from anyone is appreciated.